# how to redirect different pages in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to redirect user pages according to status of the user. I wrote a method in My Controller in Laravel 5.2 where status 1 is working but when I add else and else if function it generate following errror.

```
FatalErrorException in ProjectCollaboratorsController.php line 219: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)
```

My controller method is folllowing

```
public function show($id){
 if (Permission::where('status', 1)->where('project_id', $id)->exists())
 {

    $project = Project::find($id);
    $tasks = $this->getTasks($id);
    $files = $this->getFiles($id);
    $comments = $this->getComments($id);
    $collaborators = $this->getCollaborators($id);
    $permissions = $this->getPermissions($id);



    return view('collaborators.show');
    }
 else
 {


    (Permission::where('status', 2)->where('project_id', $id)->exists()) 
         return view('collaborators.manager');

  }

  else if 
  {

     (Permission::where('status', 3)->where('project_id', $id)->exists()) 
         return view('collaborators.user');
  }
}
```

Comment: your code is pretty much wrong.. how can you call else before else if?

Comment: And the syntax is incorrect... it should be `elseif(my_condition) { // }`... and else{ // } at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, you will be good to go

```
public function show($id){

    if (Permission::where('status', 1)->where('project_id', $id)->exists())
    {
        $project = Project::find($id);
        $tasks = $this->getTasks($id);
        $files = $this->getFiles($id);
        $comments = $this->getComments($id);
        $collaborators = $this->getCollaborators($id);
        $permissions = $this->getPermissions($id);
        return view('collaborators.show');
    }
     else if(Permission::where('status', 2)->where('project_id', $id)->exists())
    {     
         return view('collaborators.manager');
    }
    else if (Permission::where('status', 3)->where('project_id', $id)->exists()) 
    {     
         return view('collaborators.user');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is completely wrong, try to implement with this structure..

```
public function yourFunctionName()
{
    if(condition1)
    {
            code
    }
    elseif(condition2)
    {
        code
    }
    else
    {
      code
    }
}
```